# Pass a date parameter on dblink Postgres

Tags: postgresql, function

How I pass a date parameter  to dblink on postgres ?

```
SELECT * FROM dblink
    (
       'my connection'
       ,
     'SELECT s.dtcreated  FROM realvida.tbstudente s  ' ||
     ' WHERE s.dtcreated' = $1 -- my parameter pass '02-01-2017'

    ) as result2( dtcreated date )
```

This way it returned me an error:

> operator does not exist: date = integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `'SELECT s.dtcreated  FROM realvida.tbstudente s  ' ||
     ' WHERE s.dtcreated' = $1`

to

`format('SELECT s.dtcreated  FROM realvida.tbstudente s WHERE s.dtcreated = %L',$1)`

Comment: Thank you. You help me so much.